# Puppeteer stuck in promise after await page.waitForSelector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i have this code, that should enter a login page, login, then goto new url, when ready, find div element with class ".queueRightSide" and click it.

But i am stuck at Promise.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
    headless: 'new',
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://app.bizzy.dk/Login', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  console.log('Now on page: ' + page.url());

  page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
  console.log('Beginning log in');
  await page.type('#Username', '123@example.dk');
  await page.type('#Password', 'test123');
  await Promise.all([
    page.click('input.btn-primary'),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
  ]);
  console.log('Finished Log in');

  await page.goto('https://app.bizzy.dk/Home/Desktop', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  console.log('Now on page: ' + page.url());
  await page.waitForSelector('div.queueRightSide', { timeout: 5000 });
  console.log('Awaited div.queueRightSide without timing out');

  await Promise.all([
    page.click('div.queueRightSide'), 

    // On click, a popup with class "modal-dialog" will appear.
    // Await popup, and click on button with class "withripple" if found, otherwise show error message.
    
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
  ]);

  console.log('End of actions on page: ' + page.url());

  // Logout too, if possible, or clear login cookie with name: .ASPXAUTH
  await browser.close();
}

main();
```

This is my output when running script:

```
Now on page: https://app.bizzy.dk/Login
Beginning log in
Finished Log in
Now on page: https://app.bizzy.dk/Home/Desktop
Awaited div.queueRightSide without timing out
/home/user/Documents/phone_script/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/Deferred.js:27
                    this.reject(new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(opts.message));
                                ^

TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
```

Comment: Is it possible that firing a click at `div.queueRightSide` causes navigation before you waited for it? What happens if you change the array order in `Promise.all`?

Comment: Or, if this is an SPA, does clicking `div.queueRightSide` even cause a navigation (i.e. a reload or a "proper" navigation to a new URL)?

Comment: Which line is timing out? `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),` seems [spurious](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not had very good luck with `waitForNavigation()`

Just use - `await page.waitForSelector(elementLocatorString,{ visible: true, timeout: (5000) })`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).